# iOS: Switching Views using Static Methods?

Tags: objective-c, ios4

Is it acceptable to create a static method (or UIViewController) responsible for switching views? It would be static to make it a sort-of "global" method (or UIViewController).

I haven't fully grasped a good way to switch one view out of memory, and replace it with another.

Answer (score 0):

it depends on the hierarchy of your views but most of the time, you don't need to use class methods for UI stuffs.

For example, if you have a toolbox view that you use to switch between difference views of your application, you can implement the toolbox as a singleton and the switching methods will be of this singleton instance, instead of the Toolbox class.

about switching a view out of memory, once again, it depends of the relation between your views. you won't release a modal view that you often show, or a streamline of the activities of your user. some views should be kept in memory while others (configuration views for example) can be released as they are shown off.

the real downside of using class methods for UI stuff is that you lose flexibility: you can't really adapt to the context of the instance. So you should stick with instance methods, imho.